# Mapbox Annotation Callout

Tags: ios, swift, annotations, mapbox, callout

I have recently decided to change from Mapkit to Mapbox. I have my annotations implemented within my map but for some reason my annotation callouts are not appearing when I click on the annotation. I am quite confused and unsure as to why this is not appearing. Hopefully somebody can help! The appropriate code is shown below:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import Mapbox

class ViewController: UIViewController, SideBarDelegate, MGLMapViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MGLMapView!


//Filtering annotations for sidebar

func sideBarDidSelectButtonAtIndex(_ index: Int) {
   mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations!)

    for park in skateparks {

        if index == 0 {
            addAnnotation(park: park)
        }

        if index == 1 && park.type == .park {
            addAnnotation(park: park)
        }

        if index == 2 && park.type == .street {
            addAnnotation(park: park)
        }


    }

}

var sideBar: SideBar = SideBar()

var skateparks = [Skatepark]()

let locationsRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "locations")

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    //Location

    mapView.delegate = self
    mapView.showsUserLocation = true

    //Sidebar

    sideBar = SideBar(sourceView: self.view, skateItems: ["All Skate Spots", "Skateparks", "Street Skating"])
    sideBar.delegate = self


    // Passing firebase annotation data

    locationsRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        self.skateparks.removeAll()

        for item in snapshot.children {
            guard let snapshot = item as? FIRDataSnapshot else { continue }

            let newSkatepark = Skatepark(snapshot: snapshot)

            self.skateparks.append(newSkatepark)

            self.addAnnotation(park: newSkatepark)
        }
    })
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    view.sendSubview(toBack: mapView)
}


func addAnnotation(park: Skatepark) {

    let point = MGLPointAnnotation()

    point.coordinate = park.coordinate

    point.title = park.name

    point.subtitle = park.subtitle

    mapView.addAnnotation(point)

    mapView.selectAnnotation(point, animated: true)

}
}

func mapView(mapView: MGLMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLAnnotationView? {
return nil
}


func mapView(mapView: MGLMapView, annotationCanShowCallout annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> Bool {
return true
}
```

Comment: have you implemented the delegate for annotations?

Comment: Hey Tushar, I have!

Comment: You can check this once-: https://www.mapbox.com/help/first-steps-ios-sdk/

Comment: Hey, I have read and re-read this document and all my code looks correct! I cannot see any reason why this is not working

Comment: can you show more code?

Comment: are you using swift3?

Comment: I am using swift 3, I have also edited my code above to show more

Comment: update your swift 3 function-: func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, annotationCanShowCallout annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> Bool {
    // Always try to show a callout when an annotation is tapped.
    return true
}

Comment: similerly-: func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work, although I should have had the update in the first place! I assume you meant: func mapView(_mapView: MGLMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLAnnotationView? {
    return nil
}

Comment: instead of nil return a view.

Comment: what view should I return?

Comment: i updated that function again try it once.

Comment: it is ok nil should still return you a standard annotation.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE YOUR SWIFT 3 FUNCTIONS-:**

```
  func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, annotationCanShowCallout annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> Bool { // Always try to show a callout when an annotation is tapped. return true }


 func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

}
```

Comment: I have updated the functions but the callout is still not visible!

Comment: It says optional can only be applied to protocol members. And did you mean to do the code like this?                                                                func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, annotationCanShowCallout annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> Bool {
    
    return true

}

   optional func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, viewFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLAnnotationView? {
        
    return nil
        
}

Comment: But I am not using Mapkit? I am using Mapbox

Answer (score 0):

You may find [this example](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/callout-delegate/) helpful (if you have not already seen it)!
 It shows how to use the Mapbox callout delegate.